# Hide Anchor tag based on href URL

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I was wondering if there is a possibility to HIDE anchor tags that refer to a particular URL.
I know there is possible to hide based on id like this with JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('someID').style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<a href="#" id="someID" style="display: none">Check</a>
```

But let's say I want to hide all anchor tags based on URL example: www.example.com

```
<a href="www.example.com" id="someID" style="display: none">Check</a>
<a href="www.example2.com" id="someID" style="display: none">Check</a>
```

I want to hide the first anchor tag, not the second that refers to example2.com

Is this possible with pure JavaScript and not jQuery?

Comment: @Ayush No, i want to hide all the a href elements that have url=example.com and not url=example2.com. the ID can be same ("someID")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to select bu attribute value like this.I have used no jquery the only javascript is used.

```js
document.querySelector("[href='www.example.com']").style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<a href="www.example.com" id="someID" style="display:block">Check</a>
<a href="www.example2.com" id="someID" style="display:block">Check</a>
```

Comment: Glad it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through all anchor elements and then check their `href`:

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  if (anchors[i].href == 'https://example.com/') {
    anchors[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com/" id="someID">Check</a>
<a href="https://example2.com/" id="someID">Check</a>
```

Comment: Your answer was very like @Mayank's answer. I think your code and his are doing the same thing? Loop all anchor tags then if found href=example.com then hide it. or am i wrong?

Comment: @Asim It ends up doing the same thing, but in a different way.  My solution gets all of the `<a>` elements, loops through them and checks each to see if the href is matching. @Mayanak's answer actually uses a nifty CSS selector which selects all elements with a href of `www.example.com`, then simultaneously sets all of the displays to none. Their answer is actually much better and more efficient, I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make condition

```
var url = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

if (url.href = "www.example.com")
{
url.style.display = none;
}
```

It is not exact code. i provided you example .kindly try it and let me know. It is for single . if you have many tags then loop all those

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to do the job. Use `querySelector` to get all the elements with same `id`. Then loop the `ids` and compare the `href` link value.

```
<script>
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id='someID']");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].getAttribute("href") === "www.example.com") {
    elements[i].style.display='none';
  }
}
</script>
```

[Working fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/se7kszkw/1/)

Comment: This will work, but if i have different ID on some places this code will not work. Ive formulated the question wrong sorry but @Mayank's answer covers this issue :) thanks anyway