Is it possible to hide #section name in a URL?
When you click a link in a navigation bar, it scrolls to a section of the page that it's linked to. However, it leaves #section_name in the URL.
I was wondering if there was a way to remove this or even just git rid of the #. It makes the URL look a little ugly (IMO).

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888437/hide-anchor-tag-based-on-href-url

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165479/how-to-hide-an-anchor-tag-by-href-id-using-css

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186054/how-to-hide-an-anchor-tag-by-the-id-of-the-href

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045303/how-to-hide-anchor-tag-from-url

Yes, this should work without changing the URL, but it uses JavaScript:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#content1" class="scroll-link">Go to Content 1</a>
    <a href="#content2" class="scroll-link">Go to Content 2</a>

    <div id="content1">      
        <h2>This is the content 1</h2>
        <p>Here is some example content.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="content2">      
        <h2>This is the content 2</h2>
        <p>Here is some example content.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        const scrollLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-link');

        scrollLinks.forEach(function(link) {
            link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const targetId = this.getAttribute('href');
                document.querySelector(targetId).scrollIntoView();
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>


I like this version the best. It's clean and relatively simple. I'm currently working on a project, and havent gotten to the specific part where I need to implement this. When I get there, I'll get back to you on whether it works out or not. (if it does I'll just mark yours as the answer)

try this


document.getElementById('thing1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const thing2 = document.getElementById('thing2');
  const thing2position = thing2.getBoundingClientRect();
  window.scrollTo({
    top: thing2position.top + window.scrollY,
    left: thing2position.left + window.scrollX,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
document.getElementById('thing2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const thing1 = document.getElementById('thing1');
  const thing1position = thing1.getBoundingClientRect();
  window.scrollTo({
    top: thing1position.top + window.scrollY,
    left: thing1position.left + window.scrollX,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
#thing2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1000px;
}
<body>
    <a href="#" id="thing1">first thing</a>
    <a href="#" id="thing2">second thing</a>
</body>



